# Menu dropdown and checking if it is current item and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, menu

I want to create a dropdown menu With English or German as the options in JavaScript / jQuery that checks that:

```
check if on a domain  - say happy.com/pizza 
if german is selected on dropdown 
redirect user to 
happy.de/pizza
and I could have a list

if happy.com/pizza got to happy.de/pizza  
happy.com/coke got to happy.de/coke  
happy.com/juice got to happy.de/juice
etc etc.
```

I have written the code yet but how would one go about this?

I have written some code but I just need a little help please:

In this scenario I am on the www.something.com/beer page and want it to go to the German Beer Page!

```
<select>
    <option value="1">English</option>
    <option value="2">German</option>
</select>

if(value == 2)  && is current domain www.something.com/beer{
    window.top.location.href = 'www.something.de/beer'; 
}else if(value == 2)  && is current domain www.something.com/cheese{
    window.top.location.href = 'www.something.de/cheese'; 
}else{
    do nothing
}
```

How do I get this to check the value of the dropdown and the domain is currently on?

Here is my Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/msasz2an/

I am really stuck on the && is current section how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (value == 2 && location.href.indexOf('www.something.com/beer') >= 0) {
    window.top.location.href = 'www.something.de/beer'; 
} else if (value == 2 && location.href.indexOf('www.something.com/cheese') >= 0) {
    window.top.location.href = 'www.something.de/cheese'; 
} else {

}
```

`location.href` - returns current url, `indexOf` checks if in current url there is your string

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/atarasyuk/s3wxbLo4/1/)